# Restful server access of an application is working on android 2.3 but not in the latest android

Tags: android, angularjs, apk, sling

I created a mobile application client side is done in angularjs and server side is done using sling. After creating the apk The application is working fine on the web browser and in older version of android(2.3) but however it fails to fetch information from the from the server side in the latest version of the android. Dose it have something to do with access origin? Can anyone help?

Comment: I have recently solved this problem, you can go to the config.xml file and change the folllowing : <access origin="*"/>